# Keeping count of clicks of <a> tag (non-JS)

Tags: python, django

In a Django mobile web app I'm building, I'm using the `sms` html tag in one particular template. I.e. the typical `<a href="sms:/* phone number here */?body=/* body text here */">Link</a>`. Every time the user presses `Link`, they're redirected to their phone's default SMS app with a prepopulated message.

How can one implement a counter that increments every time a user clicks `Link`? The challenge is to solely use Python/Django (server-side), no JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement a model to track clicks on `Link`. To track, you can create something like redirection view which redirects to `sms` URI after tracking click.

A basic example would be:

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponseRedirectBase

HttpResponseRedirectBase.allowed_schemes += ['sms']

class SMSRedirect(HttpResponseRedirect):
    pass

def track_count(request):
    phone = request.GET.get('phone', '')
    body = request.GET.body('body', '')
    link = build_sms_link(phone, body)
    link.hits += 1
    link.save()
    return SMSRedirect(link.url)
```

By default `HttpResponseRedirectBase` does not allow non-web schemes/protocols. You can make it allow by monkey-patching its allowed schemes list.